# Accordion from template not working with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS and currently I've been using it in my project which has a an admin template that I've downloaded.

It's been working fine until I added AngularJS to it.

One of its problems is that the accordion on my navbar no longer works.

My accordion:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked main-menu">
    <li class="accordion">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
            <span> Anouncements</span> 
            <span class="accordion-arrow pull-right">
            <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>
            </span>
       </a>
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li>
               <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Browse Announcements">
                   <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Browse
               </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Create Announcement">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Create
              </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My app.js

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
              }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it by enclosing my code in an IFFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) which I learned from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIXMpXqp9lM) video.

```
(function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
          }]);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular likely doesn't know what to display. You have your router initialized with a redirect, but no actual routes configured.

It could be a lot of things, though. Without a [plunker](http://plnkr.co) of the relevant code it's hard to accurately troubleshoot.